# Reading from file not fast enough, how would I speed it up?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, .net-2.0, io

This is the way I read file:

```
    public static string readFile(string path)
    {
        StringBuilder stringFromFile = new StringBuilder();
        StreamReader SR;
        string S;
        SR = File.OpenText(path);
        S = SR.ReadLine();
        while (S != null)
        {
            stringFromFile.Append(SR.ReadLine());
        }
        SR.Close();
        return stringFromFile.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is it so long (the .txt file is about 2.5 megs). Took over 5 minutes. Is there a better way?

**Solution taken**

```
    public static string readFile(string path)
    {

       return File.ReadAllText(path);

    }
```

Took less than 1 second... :)

Comment: I'd hope it would take rather a lot less than 1 second. 2.5MB really is a very small amount of data...

Comment: I know, I had an infinite loop this is why it took so long, time to take a break I think :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving aside the horrible variable names and the lack of a using statement (you won't close the file if there are any exceptions) that should be okay, and *certainly* shouldn't take 5 minutes to read 2.5 megs.

Where does the file live? Is it on a flaky network share?

By the way, the only difference between what you're doing and using File.ReadAllText is that you're losing line breaks. Is this deliberate? How long does ReadAllText take?

Comment: Off topic, but Jon, I enjoyed your appearance on Dot Net Rocks.

Comment: @Giovanni: Great - it was a lot of fun, if somewhat nerve-wracking.

Answer (score 8):

```
S = SR.ReadLine();
while (S != null)
{
    stringFromFile.Append(SR.ReadLine());
}
```

Of note here, `S` is never set after that initial `ReadLine()`, so the `S != null` condition never triggers if you enter the while loop.  Try:

```
S = SR.ReadLine();
while (S != null)
{
    stringFromFile.Append(S = SR.ReadLine());
}
```

or use one of the other comments.

If you need to remove newlines, use string.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")

Comment: You are right +1 too. Thx, this is the reason it took so long. I took some code on the web and try to clean it up. My mistake!

Comment: actually, wouldn't this miss the first line of the file?

Answer (score 6):

```
return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Answer (score 3):

Marcus Griep has it right.  IT's taking so long because YOU HAVE AN INFINITE LOOP.  copied your code and made his changes and it read a 2.4 M text file in less than a second.

but I think you might miss the first line of the file.  Try this.

```
S = SR.ReadLine();
while (S != null){
    stringFromFile.Append(S);
    S = SR.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the entire 2.5 Mb in memory at once?

If not, I would try to work with what you need.

Comment: This is good advice.  I had a colleague who seemed to think he needed an entire 300+MB XML file in memory at once.  Didn't work too well.

Comment: I once tried to read a 500+ MB XML file into a DOM. Needless to say, it didn't work. It sat there for like minutes before throwing an OutOfMemoryException. I did some research and found that a DOM uses four to ten times as mach memory as the as the size of the XML-file. In end I used a hybrid: an XmlTextRead to create "domlet" for each "record". "Less is more" is usually good programming advise.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.IO.File.RealAllLines instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx

Alternatively, estimating the character count and passing that to StringBuilder's constructor as the capacity should speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should be much faster:

```
var str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
return str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Comment: Faster than System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);?

Comment: @Daok: You're right. My point was the use of `Replace`. I overlooked the easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

By the way: Next time you're in a similar situation, try pre-allocating memory. This improves runtime drastically, regardless of the exact data structures you use. Most containers (`StringBuilder` as well) have a constructor that allow you to reserve memory. This way, less time-consuming reallocations are necessary during the read process.

For example, you could write the following if you want to read data from a file into a `StringBuilder`:

```
var info = new FileInfo(path);
var sb = new StringBuilder((int)info.Length);
```

(Cast necessary because `System.IO.FileInfo.Length` is `long`.)

Answer (score 1):

ReadAllText was a very good solution for me. I used following code for 3.000.000 row text file and it took 4-5 seconds to read all rows.

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(txtFilePath.Text)
string[] arr = fileContent.Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop and `StringBuilder` may be redundant; Try using 
[ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

To read a text file fastest you can use something like this

```
public static string ReadFileAndFetchStringInSingleLine(string file)
    {
        StringBuilder sb;
        try
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                    {
                        string str;
                        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sb.Append(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you. and for more info, please visit to the following link-
[Fastest Way to Read Text Files](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files)